# I am having trouble using Wininet

Tags: c++, function, upload, ftp, wininet

I am programming in `C++` and I want to upload a file to my web server which i have already done using the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet")


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  HINTERNET hInternet;
  HINTERNET hFtp;

  hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL,NULL,0);
  hFtp = InternetConnect(hInternet, L"ftp.freetzi.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, L"myuser.freetzi.com", "mypassword", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);

  FtpPutFile(hFtp, L"C:\\deneme.txt", L"coolName.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);

  if ( FtpPutFile(hFtp, L"C:\\deneme.txt", L"coolName.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0) )
  {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Upload Successful.", L"Title", NULL);
  }
  else
  {
            //This is the message I get...
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Upload Failed.", L"Title", NULL);
  }


  InternetCloseHandle(hFtp);
  InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);


  return 0;
}
```

But as this program will be used by many people, I can't find a way to rename the uploaded file `coolname.txt`  if the target file already exists, the code above will overwrite the old data and rewrite the new one of used 2 or more times,

I tried:

1. "/public_html/log.txt" + std::to_string(rand())
2. A function:-

   `generateFileName( std::string const& directory,
                std::string const& rootName,
                 std::string const& extension )
   {
      std::ostringstream results;
      results.fill( '0' );
      results << directory << '/' << rootName << '-' << std::setw(4) << rand() 
          << extension;
      return results.str();
   }`

I however, found a way to accomplish this task using `FtpFindFirstFile` But I am unable to know how to use it. If someone could explain me more clear or give some examples, I would really appriciate.

Reference : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384180(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: The documentation for `FtpFindFirstFile` says it's similar to [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx). That function has a perfectly good example.

Comment: @chris Will it search online (in ftp) for a file?

Comment: No, but all you have to do is change it to use the FTP functions instead of the regular ones. That's what it means by "similar to". To see which functions to replace them with, look at the documentation for `FtpFindFirstFile`.

Comment: Do you just want to change the exist file name? Why don't you use 'FtpRenameFile'? 'FindFirstFile' is often used for enumeration files in certain directory.